# How to reverse engineer exponential moving average given the last known ema

Tags: python, math, logic, moving-average

I've been trying to reverse enginner a series of EMA given the last known EMA. This should be able to be done by just simple arithmetic manipulation of the exponential moving average equation :

```
Multiplier= (2 / (Time periods + 1) )
EMA = {Close - EMA(previous day)} x multiplier + EMA(previous day)
```

Which gives me:

```
EMA(previous day) = (EMA(Today) - Close * multiplier)/(1 - multiplier)
```

Hence, the following function I defined is as follows:

```
def ema(df, last_ma ,period):

    ema = [last_ma]
    k = 2/(period+1)

    for i in range(len(df)-1,0,-1):

        prev_ema = (last_ma - df['Close'][i] * k)/(1-k)
        print(last_ma, df['Close'][i], prev_ema)
        last_ma = prev_ema

        ema.append(prev_ema)

    ema.reverse()

return ema
```

The problem is that the values appended into the list `EMA` keeps getting larger and larger, which eventually went to infinity. There is nothing wrong with the data set, so I am guessing something is wrong with the logic of the code, but I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The link below is the data that I wish to work on, the last known EMA number that I am using is -23628.2 and it is a 200-period exponential moving average.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byc-aSwZI5OFd1ZWVEgxNUI5Xzg

After doing some research, my guess is that it could be due to floating point precision error when performing such calculations over a large array of data points.

Comment: fix your function indentation

Comment: can you add some sample data

Comment: Hey djk47463, i've added in the sample data. My best guess would be a floating point precision error that compounds that caused the numbers to go askew over multiple iterations.

Comment: what is the period value?

Comment: It is a 200 period exponential moving average. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that your math is unstable.

When going forward, each step multiplies the previous `EMA` by a `multiplier` between `0` and `1`.  This means that the influence of any given `Close` dies off exponentially (thus the name *Exponential* Moving Average).

However, when going backwards, each step *divides* the following `EMA` by the `multiplier`.  This means that the influence of any given data point *increases* exponentially, rather than dying out.

If your math were perfect, and you got all the numbers just right, this wouldn't matter.  However, all your floating point errors are *also* magnified exponentially, so the repeatedly amplified noise will quickly outgrow your signal.

There's no simple way to fix this.  The most obvious thing to try is to try going forwards instead of backwards, but it's not clear if that's compatible with your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! This was precisely the missing part that I was unable to explain by myself. I have decided to go with the forwards approach though it does not perfectly solve my problems, but it's good enough.